# Laravel 5.5 - Include Find function inside Validation Rule

Tags: laravel

I am using validation in an Laravel 5.5 controller like this...

```
 $membership = Membership::find($request->input('membership_id'));

    /* Validation Rules */
    $rules = [
        'key' => [
            'required',
            Rule::in([$membership->key]),
        ],
    ];
```

This works correctly if membership_id is provided, but if not then it with error....

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Is there a way I can include the Membership:find function inside of the validation Rule instead so that is respects the require validation?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am trying to check that a provided input 'key' matches the one stored in $membership->key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`optional()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-optional) helper to avoid the "Trying to get property of non-object" error:

```
Rule::in([optional($membership)->key]),
```

So, if membership will not be found, null will be returned and a user will be redirected back with validation error message.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clearer in the OP. by fail I don't mean validation fails but I get a PHP error as it cant find $membership

Comment: Thank you, optional works perfect.  Reading up on it now